# HighCharts - start drawing from the left most in a combined chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm currently trying to combine an area chart with a column chart using HighCharts. However, when I select different ranges for the chart, the column chart cannot start from the leftmost and end on the rightmost. Please see the below pics.

It looks like we have some similar questions here, but none of them works for my case.

[current_correct for 6 months](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4Ssj.png)

[need_wrong for 7 days](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHFpl.png)

The closest solution I can find is

```
              series: {
                findNearestPointBy: 'x',
                label: {
                  connectorAllowed: false
                },
                pointPlacement: 'on'
              }
            },
```

[with above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqdwB.png)

But this one only makes points without changing the coordinates on the x-axis. For example, the leftmost column in the above pic is 14.Sep but it does not at the right position.

Thanks for any help!

EDIT: It is very weird since I found that it has a smaller gap in each Monday and a larger gap in others weekday.... As the below pic.

[weird case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkJ9I.png)

Comment: Hi Yunnosch. I do not know why it shows as an anonymous user... Thanks for noticing! I've updated my question!

Comment: Please double check. It seems that two edits were merged. One with "22nd September" one with "14th September". Not sure whether both are by you. If they are then there still something weird is going on with your account.... If not then the most recent edit might not be what you wanted....

Comment: Hehehe.. I updated 22 to 14. I think maybe I forgot to login and used something like `improved this question` by mistake... Thanks!

Comment: I did mention logging in to avoid "anonymous" problems.... Please remember, it causes confusion and work for others.... Note that it also gets your desired result earlier, because while others do the work you created for them (reviewing your edit proposal), you have to wait until your edit actually becomes visible to others here. Note that you do see your edit, but others don't. So the improvement on your post is delayed and the missing correction could meanwhile attract the wrong kind of attention. Also, frankly, this lack of care on your part annoys me.

Comment: Sorry. I'm new to stack overflow. This is actually my first question.. I'm really sorry about that.

Comment: Hi @ShuoWang, could you reproduce your issue on some online editor which I could work on? For now, I can only guess that maybe `dataGrouping` has something common with this behaviour - https://www.highcharts.com/docs/stock/data-grouping